# XML Parsing Where xml tag is having attribute and value

Tags: xml, parsing

I need help. I have to fetch values from a xml file. My XML  is of following type.

```
<CREDIT_SUMMARY BorrowerID="Borrower" _Name="TransUnionCreditSummaryDescription">
    <_DATA_SET _Name="SummaryType" _Value="R"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="HighCredit" _Value="5128"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="CreditLimit" _Value="23600"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="Balance" _Value="13364"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="AmountPastDue" _Value="0"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="MonthlyPayment" _Value="148"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="PercentOfCreditAvailable" _Value="43"></_DATA_SET>
    <_Text>TransUnion Credit Summary: Revolving or Check Credit Accounts</_Text>
</CREDIT_SUMMARY>
```

I have to get the value of _Name and _Value which is inside of the xml tag.

Thanks,

Comment: You example is no valid XML. Please post a correct example.

Comment: You want to parse it with wich language? Also StackOverflow is not a code factory. Try by yourself and if you experienced problem then ask from help here posting an SSCCE.

Comment: @ceving My copy of Harold and Means tells me that XML element and attribute names can start with an underscore character.  It's unusual, but apparently valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp) expression to get the attribute identifier of the first and second attribute:

```
//_DATA_SET/@*[position() = 1 or position() = 2]/name()
```

Or this to get the values:

```
//_DATA_SET/@*[position() = 1 or position() = 2]/string()
```

[Saxon HE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/) can be used to perform the query on the command line:

```
$ cat credit.xml 
<CREDIT_SUMMARY BorrowerID="Borrower" _Name="TransUnionCreditSummaryDescription">
    <_DATA_SET _Name="SummaryType" _Value="R"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="HighCredit" _Value="5128"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="CreditLimit" _Value="23600"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="Balance" _Value="13364"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="AmountPastDue" _Value="0"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="MonthlyPayment" _Value="148"></_DATA_SET>
    <_DATA_SET _Name="PercentOfCreditAvailable" _Value="43"></_DATA_SET>
    <_Text>TransUnion Credit Summary: Revolving or Check Credit Accounts</_Text>
</CREDIT_SUMMARY>
$ java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:credit.xml -qs:'//_DATA_SET/@*[position() = 1 or position() = 2]/string()' '!omit-xml-declaration=yes'
SummaryType R HighCredit 5128 CreditLimit 23600 Balance 13364 AmountPastDue 0 MonthlyPayment 148 PercentOfCreditAvailable 43
```